How to guarantee the existence of a std::chrono::tzdb at program startup?
Is there a way to determine whether or not a timezone database is initialized at the start of a program?
My aim is to not have a std::runtime_error thrown mid program because of a non-existent tzdb. I need the timezone database to be guaranteed to exist during the program's lifetime.
A primitive example:
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <stdexcept>


int main( )
{
    try
    {
        std::cout << std::chrono::get_tzdb_list().front().current_zone()->name() << '\n';
    }
    catch ( const std::runtime_error& re )
    {
        std::cout << re.what( ) << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

// rest of the program that happily references the `std::chrono::time_zone` objects in
// the database with no errors
}

If I'm not mistaken, the very first call to std::chrono::get_tzdb_list() in a program tries to initialize the database and it throws if it doesn't succeed.
But obviously, the above method is not ideal since I don't want to print the name of the current zone. How can this be achieved without printing anything and still making sure that the compiler doesn't optimize the call to std::chrono::get_tzdb_list() out?

Compilers don't optimize away function calls with side effects. If it's get_tzdb_list that initializes the database, then (void)std::chrono::get_tzdb_list(); is enough.

The function might throw – and you have some output in that case. If it did optimise out it would change the behaviour of the programme (violate the 'as if' rule), thus should not be allowed to do that optimisation anyway. So you shoundn't need any further measures either.

@HolyBlackCat Or [[ maybe_unused ]] const auto& tzdb_list = std::chrono::get_tzdb_list( );?

@digito_evo Sure, if you want to. I consider (void) to be superior (at least in function parameters because it prevents you from being able to easily copy-paste the signature between the declaration and the definition; elsewhere just for consistency).

Just get_tzdb() should be sufficient.  I like to put it in a detached thread so that it can happen concurrently with other initialization jobs:
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int
main()
{
    std::thread{
        []()
        {
            try
            {
                (void)std::chrono::get_tzdb();
            }
            catch (std::exception const& e)
            {
                std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
                throw;
            }
        }
    }.detach();
    // ...
}

The access is thread-safe.  If the main part of the program tries to access tzdb prior to this thread, one of them will get there first, and the other will block until the first access is complete.

Please take a look at my fully detailed question here if you'd like to.

I looked at it.  Looks fine to me.  Your requirements are more complex than you show here.  I often just boil mine down to thread{get_tzdb}.detach(); in main as if there is a failure, the program terminates due to an uncaught exception, and my environment already gives a good diagnostic for that, including the exception's what().  In the common case there is not a failure, I get up and running as fast as possible.

I see. That's one strategy. However I want my program to spend a little bit of time in advance (before main) to set up the database and also create a complete list of zone names because they will be used at some point later in the program.

Do you think I've done it correctly when it comes to appending the names of zones and zone links? I want to show all of them to the user so they can choose their preferred zone out of 597 names (on the std library implementation that I use).

I haven't compiled  and tested it, but yes, it looks fine to me.  Warning:  Just within the last 24h I've become aware that the IANA time zone database guys have introduced links to links since C++20.  C++ vendors have just become aware of it.  If a client searches for such a name the result is likely to be locate_zone not finding the time_zone.  The previous IANA rule was that a link always pointed to a time zone, and not to another link.  Those IANA guys are so fun to work with...

Oh that's kinda hilarious that all these changes in the standards and infrastructure are taking place while I'm working on my current project. I don't know what I should reply on haha. Thanks for letting me know. Although I think I don't have an issue yet since I won't let the user type the name. Instead I prompt them to enter a number from 1 to 597 to basically choose one of the displayed zones.
